# How did the spirit world know, that Hiei has sister?

Tags: yu-yu-hakusho

In Yu Yu Hakusho, when Koenma said that Yukina was held hostage in one of the houses of the oligarchs. At the end, he also said that Yukina is Hiei's sister. How did the Spirit World find out that Hei was born in the ice kingdom, and also how did they know that Yukina is Hiei's sister? They didn't even know that Yusuke had demonic blood in his blood

Comment: Hello! I would like to help you answer the question, but I would be glad if you would direct me to which episode it was you pointed on.

Comment: @USerNAme That was before the Dark Tournament arc, when they met Togura first time. Koenma gave cassette to Yusuke, where he told theirs mission (save Yukina), in cassete he also said, that Yukina is Hiei’s sister.

Comment: That "Cassette" scene is in episode 22 (which what I wanted to know, but I figured out which episode anyway by you description).By the look of it and how it seems, Koenma "agents" did good deep job figuring out who she is. there's not seems some "great reason" to how it is. when you scout to help some helpless girl you usually investigate deep enough to know enough details. that's what I think.